# Java: SortedMap, TreeMap, Comparable? How to use?

Tags: java, interface, comparator, treemap, sortedmap

I have a list of objects I need to sort according to properties of one of their fields. I've heard that SortedMap and Comparators are the best way to do this.

1. Do I implement Comparable with the class I'm sorting, or do I create a new class?
2. How do I instantiate the SortedMap and pass in the Comparator?
3. How does the sorting work? Will it automatically sort everything as new objects are inserted?

**EDIT:**
This code is giving me an error:

```
private TreeMap<Ktr> collection = new TreeMap<Ktr>();
```

(Ktr implements `Comparator<Ktr>`). Eclipse says it is expecting something like `TreeMap<K, V>`, so the number of parameters I'm supplying is incorrect.

Comment: You need a TreeSet, not a TreeMap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The simpler way is to implement `Comparable` with your existing objects, although you could instead create a `Comparator` and pass it to the `SortedMap`.
   Note that [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) are two different things; a class implementing `Comparable` compares `this` to another object, while a class implementing `Comparator` compares two *other* objects.
2. If you implement `Comparable`, you don't need to pass anything special into the constructor. Just call `new TreeMap<MyObject>()`. (**Edit:** Except that of course `Maps` need two generic parameters, not one. Silly me!)
   If you instead create another class implementing `Comparator`, pass an instance of that class into the constructor.
3. Yes, according to the [`TreeMap` Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

---

**Edit:** On re-reading the question, none of this makes sense. If you already have a list, the sensible thing to do is implement `Comparable` and then call [`Collections.sort`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) on it. No maps are necessary.

A little code:

```
public class MyObject implements Comparable<MyObject> {
    // ... your existing code here ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyObject other) {
        // do smart things here
    }
}

// Elsewhere:
List<MyObject> list = ...;
Collections.sort(list);
```

As with the `SortedMap`, you could instead create a `Comparator<MyObject>` and pass it to [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? I would implement Comparable with the list instead of with the class being sorted?

Answer (score 3):

1.

That depends on the situation. Let's say the object A should sort before the object B in your set. If it generally makes sense to consider A less than B, then implementing Comparable would make sense. If the order only makes sense in the context in which you use the set, then you should probably create a Comparator.

2.

```
new TreeMap(new MyComparator());
```

Or without creating a MyComparator class:

```
new TreeMap(new Comparator<MyClass>() {
    int compare(MyClass o1, MyClass o2) { ... }
});
```

3. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a list and get an error because you have one argument on the map I  suppose you want a sorted set:

```
SortedSet<Ktr> set = new TreeSet<Ktr>(comparator);
```

This will keep the set sorted, i.e. an iterator will return the elements in their sort order. There are also methods specific to [SortedSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) which you might want to use. If you also want to go backwards you can use [NavigableSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html).

Answer (score 1):

My answer assumes you are using the `TreeMap` implementation of `SortedMap`.

1.) If using `TreeMap`, you have a choice.  You can either implement `Comparable` directly on your class or pass a separate `Comparator` to the constructor.

2.) Example:

```
Comparator<A> cmp = new MyComparator();
Map<A,B> map = new TreeMap<A,B>(myComparator);
```

3.) Yes that's correct.  Internally [TreeMap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) uses a red-black tree to store elements in order as they are inserted; the time cost of performing an insert (or retrieval) is O(log N).

Answer (score 0):

You make a `Comparator<ClassYouWantToSort>`.  Then the Comparator compares the field that you want to sort on.

When you create the `TreeMap`, you create a `TreeMap<ClassYouWantToSort>`, and you pass in the `Comparator` as an argument.  Then, as you insert objects of type `ClassYouWantToSort`, the `TreeMap` uses your `Comparator` to sort them properly.

EDIT: As Adamski notes, you can also make `ClassYouWantToSort` itself `Comparable`.  The advantage is that you have fewer classes to deal with, the code is simpler, and `ClassYouWantToSort` gets a convenient default ordering.  The disadvantage is that `ClassYouWantToSort` may not have a single obvious ordering, and so you'll have to implement `Comparables` for other situations anyway.  You also may not be able to change `ClassYouWantToSort`.

EDIT2: If you only have a bunch of objects that you're throwing into the collection, and it's not a `Map` (i.e. it's not a mapping from one set of objects to another) then you want a `TreeSet`, not a `TreeMap`.