# Java "cannot cast to Comparable" when using TreeMap

Tags: java, casting, treemap, comparable, sortedmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: SortedMap, TreeMap, Comparable? How to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440006/java-sortedmap-treemap-comparable-how-to-use)

I am using the Java [JungI](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html) graph package and Netbeans 7. I am getting the following error from Java:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: graphvisualization.MyVertex cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
```

Here is the code associated with the error:

```
SortedMap<MyVertex, Double> vMap = new TreeMap<MyVertex, Double>();
       double curRank = 0;
       for(MyVertex v: g.getVertices())                 //g is a SparseGraph<MyVertex, MyEdge>
       {
           curRank = vertexRank.getVertexScore(v);
           vMap.put(v, curRank);                        //**Here is my Error**
       }
```

Class MyVertex is a class I made for graphs. The following is the code for MyVertex

```
public class MyVertex 
{
    int vID;                    //id for this vertex
    double centrality;          //centrality measure for this vertex
    int degree;                 //the degree of this vertex

    public MyVertex(int id)
    {
        this.vID = id;
        this.centrality=0;
        this.degree=0;
    }

    public double getCentrality()
    {
        return this.centrality;
    }

    public void setCentrality(double centrality)
    {
        this.centrality = centrality;
    }

    public int getDegree()
    {
        return this.degree;
    }

    public void setDegree(int deg)
    {
        this.degree = deg;
    }

    public void incrementDegree()
    {
        this.degree++;
    }

    public void decrementDegree()
    {
        this.degree--;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "v"+vID;
    }

    int compareTo(MyVertex v) 
    {
        return (this.degree < v.degree) ? 1 : 0;          //this will do descendingly
    }
}
```

1. How do I get MyVertex types to be casted to Comparables?
2. Why is this necessary? (I do not immediately see the reason)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How do I get MyVertex types to be casted to Comparables?

Implement Comparable interface.

```
public class MyVertex implements Comparable<MyVertex> {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o) {
   // comparison logic goes here

  }
 }
```

or alternately, you can pass a `comparator` to the constructor of `TreeMap`.

```
 new TreeMap<MyVertex, Double>(new Comparator<MyVertex>()
        {
            public int compare(MyVertex o1, MyVertex o2)
            {
                //comparison logic goes here
            } 
    });
```

> Why is this necessary?

Because you are storing in tree map which is a sorted map (sorted by keys). Map Keys need to be comparable to ensure a sort order in the map.

Answer (score 10):

The behaviour is compliant with the [javadoc of TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

> Throws ClassCastException if the specified key cannot be compared with the keys currently in the map

There are essentially two ways to make it work:

- either make `MyVertex` implement `Comparable<MyVertex>`
- or pass a `Comparator<MyVertex>` to the constructor of your TreeMap

Note that before Java 7, the exception would only be thrown when adding a second item to the map whereas with Java 7 the exception is thrown when adding one item to the map.

Comment: last note is interesting

Answer (score 5):

`MyVertex` class should implement `Comparable` as tree map uses the compareTo method to order the map based on keys.

```
public class MyVertex implements Comparable<MyVertex> {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyVertex o) {
   // do the comparison logic

  }
 }
```

Other option is to pass a Comparator Object to TreeMap
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#TreeMap(java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 0):

Your class has not implemented Comparable interface.

You have method compareTo(); so just add **implements Comparable** to your class **MyVertex** .

Answer (score 0):

**-** First you should make class MyVertex implement Comparable.

**Eg:**

```
public class MyVertex implements Comparable {

  @Override
  public int compareTo(MyVertex o) {


  }
 }
```

**-** But if you want to **compare on the basis of more than one attribute of the object**, then its better to use `java.util.Comparator<T>` interface.

```
new TreeMap<MyVertex, Double>(new Comparator<MyVertex>()
        {
            public int compare(MyVertex o1, MyVertex o2)
            {

            } 
    });
```